# c++0x inherited constructor in templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, c++11, inherited-constructors

Here is class foo:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
        t = nullptr;
    }

    foo(T* p, bool flag)
    {
        t = p;
    }
private:
    T* t;
};
```

Here is class bar:

```
template <typename T>
struct bar: public foo<T>
{
    using foo<T>::foo<T>;
};
```

Is it correct syntax for inheriting constructors? If I use "using foo::foo;" then compiler of Visual C++ 2010 dies.
So basically how to inherit constructors from template classes in VC++ 2010?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct bar: public foo<T>
{
    using foo<T>::foo<T>;
};
```

To let this parse correctly, you would need to insert `template` before the `foo<T>;`, to tell the compiler that `foo` is to be regarded as a template name (it cannot look into `foo<T>` to tell itself, since `T` is unknown). But using `::template` is not allowed in a using declaration. The name also does not refer to all constructors of `bar`: Instead, it would refer to a specific constructor function template specialization (`T` is the template argument) of such a constructor as follows

```
template<typename T>
foo();
```

In addition, it's not valid for a using declaration to use a `template-id` (like `foo<T>`) as its name (which in effect forbids it to refer to function template specialization, with the addition of forbidding to name conversion function template specializations stated too), so even if you correct the parsing problem using `::template` (if it would be possible), you would still error out at this point.

When inherited constructors were introduced, special rules were added that allow to reference a constructor using a syntactic rule: If you have a qualified-id (which basically a qualified name using `...::...`), and the last qualified before the final part names a specific class, then you can denote the constructor(s) of that class in two additional ways:

- If the class was named using a template-id (a name of the form `foo<T>`) and the final part matches the template name (so, `foo<T>::foo` or `TTP<T>::TTP` with `TTP` being a template template parameter).
- If the final part matches the class name (so, `foo::foo` or `T::T`, with `T` being a template parameter).

These two additional rules are only active in a using declaration. And they were naturally not present in C++03. The other rule that was also present in C++03 is: If the final part names the injected class name, then this qualified name also refers to the constructor:

- `foo::foo` would therefor work. But with this rule alone, `T::T` (where `T` denotes class `foo`) would not work, because `foo` has no member called `T`.

Therefor, with the special rules in place you can write

```
using foo<T>::foo;
using bar::foo::foo; // valid too
```

The second is valid too: `foo` is the injected class name which was injected into the base class `foo<T>` and inherited to `bar`. We refer to that name by `bar::foo`, and then add the last part `foo`, which refers to the injected class name again, to denote the constructor(s) of `foo.

Now you understand why the initial name you tried would refer to a constructor function template specialization (if it were to be allowed to): Because the `foo<T>::foo` part would name all constructors, and the `<T>` that would follow would then filter out the template and pass the type argument.

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler doesn't yet support inheriting constructors, but does support variadic macros, variadic templates and rvalue references, and a really handy type_trait, here's a really decent workaround:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <ostream>

enum Color {Red, Blue};

#define USING(Derived, Base)                                 \
    template<typename ...Args,                               \
             typename = typename std::enable_if              \
             <                                               \
                std::is_constructible<Base, Args...>::value  \
             >::type>                                        \
    Derived(Args &&...args)                                  \
        : Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }              \


template<typename Mixin>
class add_color
: public Mixin
{
    Color color;

public:
    USING(add_color, Mixin);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const add_color& x)
    {
        switch (x.color)
        {
        case Red:
            os << "Red";
            break;
        case Blue:
            os << "Blue";
            break;
        }
        os << ' ' << x.first << ' ' << x.second;
        return os;
    }
};

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    add_color<std::pair<std::string, int>> x1("five", 5);
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << '\n';
    add_color<std::pair<std::string, int>> x3;
    std::cout << "x3 = " << x3 << '\n';
    add_color<std::pair<std::string, int>> x4 = x1;
    std::cout << "x4 = " << x4 << '\n';
    std::pair<std::string, int> p;
    add_color<std::pair<std::string, int>> x5 = p;
    std::cout << "x5 = " << x5 << '\n';
}
```

If you don't have is_constructible yet, the basic idea works without it, but the "inherited constructor" will be overly greedy.

Comment: This won't compile if `Base` is abstract

Answer (score 3):

you don't need the second template parameter;

```
template <typename T>
struct bar: public foo<T>
{
    using foo<T>::foo;
};
```

should do

**edit** i withdraw that this works on g++-4.4.1, however this should be the correct syntax when the feature becomes available

Comment: error C2886: 'foo<T>' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration

Comment: it works on g++ 4.4.1; it seems vs2010 still doesn't support inherited constructors... actually try doing this; typedef foo<T> ParentType; using ParentType::ParentType

Comment: GCC hasn't got inherited constructors. Have you tried instantiating `bar`? It doesn't lookup `foo` until being instantiated.

Comment: damn, you are right, i probably did this during regular daydreaming.

Comment: "you don't need the second template parameter" => you shoudn't specify it or it compilation breaks

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have already done a good job of explaining how inheriting constructors in C++0x work. However, as of this writing, no compiler has completely implemented the entire C++0x feature set. Unfortunately that means VC++ 2010 does not yet support inheriting constructors.

The C++0x standard has not yet been published. The final draft of the standard [will be finished sometime in March](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3082.pdf), but it'll take a few more months for ISO to publish it. During that time, compiler writers are rolling out features so they'll be as C++0x compliant as possible when the standard is finalized.

I believe the latest version of GCC supports inheriting constructors, so if you must try it out now, you can use that. Of course, C++0x support is experimental and subject to change as bugs are found, etc.

Comment: Pretty much this- your code doesn't work because VS2010 doesn't support that feature, not because you did it wrong.

Comment: This makes it sound like his code is correct, which is not the case.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I never said that the OP's code is or isn't correct, the other answers cover that part well enough. But there's no way for the OP to try them out on VC++ 2010 simply because a compiler that implements the entire C++0x feature set doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I just complained about the whole situation. I understand you didn't say anything about the code's validity. But your answer and the comment by @DeadMG taken together has the effect of telling others "oh, the other answer(s) are wrong, and the code posted is correct". I should probably have addressed @DeadMG explicitly (but I didn't think that does much good, since he apparently seems to ignore what I wrote, since he also didn't comment on my answer as to why I'm wrong).

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I understand your concern, which is why I have edited my answer to make clear that there is an issue of compiler support, and that other answers explain how inherting constructors work.

Comment: @Johannes: I didn't even read your answer- you can't solve the OP's problem by correcting his syntax. The problem is that VS2010 does not support the feature, and it's really irrelevant what syntax you try to use to express a feature which is not supported.